# Create iOS Today Extensions and Android Widgets with Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: android, ios, widget, titanium, appcelerator

Is there a way to create a widget with Titanium Appcelerator?
I need to create a widget to bring the count of the mileage of a car.
I am working with Titanium SDK 5.1.2 GA and Classic development.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Titanium currently does not support Android Widgets:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-1780

Although not officially supported you might be able to bundle an Xcode-built Today Extensions similar to how you do with Watch OS 2:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Integrate_a_WatchKit_App_Built_in_Xcode

Answer (score 1):

You can create native Android widgets in Titanium without problems. See the example Alloy project (works the same with a classic project) that here: https://github.com/m1ga/ti.coronawidget

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Juan.

Well, I have some assumption of your question.

If you are considering the term `widget` as native module, yes, it will be possible. You can use an Bluetooth module (ios/android/commonjs) to communicate with your ODB2 protocol to obtain the information that you want.

If you are considering the term `widget` as we know by the Alloy framework, you can continue using, Classic and Alloy are not mutual exclusive, then you can keep with your Classic development and use some Widget requiring into your controller. You can look at [gitt.io](http://gitt.io/) for some Bluetooth Modules per example.

Comment: Hi Victor, i am talking about "iOS Widget" (The ones you can install in the lock window ) and the "Android Widget" (the ones you can install in the lock and home window )... Thanks for the answer, i will take a look to the link you send..

Comment: @JuanCarlosSalinasOjeda ah! hehehe well, Apple calls this `widget` as `Today Extensions`. And unhappily that issue on AppC JIRA that still in development. [link](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-17556). You will need to extend your App maybe using a native module. You can follow this module https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Ti.Wormhole
See u

Comment: jajaja thanks Victor... and, for Android the name is correct ?, well.. i think it will not be possible.. right ?